# Not able to merge several audio files using moviepy

Tags: python, audio, merge, webm, moviepy

I have around 245 .webm files in my directory. I want to merge all of those 245 files into one single file called output.webm. I am using python's 'moviepy' module  to achieve this.

This is what I have done so far :

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *

audio_folder='path/to/directory'

audio_files = [audio_folder+'/'+img for img in os.listdir(audio_folder) if img.endswith(".webm")]

print(audio_files)
audio = concatenate_audioclips(audio_files)
audio.write_audiofile('output.webm')
```

I am getting the following error while doing this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 17, in <module>
 audio = concatenate_audioclips(audio_files)
File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 315, in concatenate_audioclips
durations = [c.duration for c in clips]
File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
 durations = [c.duration for c in clips]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `audio_files` is a list of strings. `concatenate_audioclips` expects a list of `AudioClip` objects.

Comment: @PaulM. Thanks for your suggestion. It worked. I am answering my question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul M suggested above, I was passing list of strings to `concatenate_audioclips` function rather than `list of AudioClip Objects`. This is what I did to solve the problem.

```
audio_folder='path/to/directory'

audio_files = [audio_folder+'/'+img for img in os.listdir(audio_folder) if img.endswith(".webm")]

print(audio_files)

audios = []
for audio in audio_files :
    audios.append(AudioFileClip(audio))

audioClips = concatenate_audioclips([audio for audio in audios])
audioClips.write_audiofile('output.webm')
```